# HandlerThread replacement in Coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I have some code which uses single HandlerThread with Handler to send messages to it. Is there any way to do this with coroutines? I don't want to create new coroutine every time, I just want to execute blocks of code on the HandlerThread. Please help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are looking to execute a block of code in the main Android thread, then you can use `UI` context from `kotlinx-coroutines-android` module like this:

```
launch(UI) { 
    ... // this block of code will be executed in main thread
}
```

The above snippet sends a message to the main handler to execute your code.

If you looking for a custom handler thread for background work, then you can create a single-threaded context in one of two ways.

**Generic approach**: Use `newSingleThreadedContext()` like this:

```
val ctx = newSingleThreadedContext() // define your context

launch(ctx) { ... } // use it to submit your code there
```

**Android-specific approach**: Create new Android `Handler`, use `Handler.asCoroutineDispatcher()` extension to convert it to the coroutines context extension. Then you'll be able to use `launch` to send your blocks of code for execution.

Comment: Yes I know that this is possible but doesn't it cause overhead if I create a new coroutine (and runnable) every time I want to run code on that thread? Now I am using HandlerThread with handler to send Messages to Handler, which in turn handles these Messages on the HandlerThread. Is it okay to create a new coroutine, for example, every 2 seconds ?

Comment: It is Ok to create new coroutine every 2 seconds. Coroutines are very, very light-weight.

Comment: Thanks, I just wasn't sure if it would not cause overhead, because every block of code launched on handler as a dispatcher creates a new Runnable too. I accepted your answer.